# Как преобразовать число из римских цифр в десятичные?

Tags: java

Делаю конвертер из римских цифр в десятичные и вот который час танцую с бубном перед ошибкой, но как то никак...

```
public static int roman2Decimal(String roman){
    int integerValue = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < roman.length(); i++) {
        char ch = roman.charAt(i);
        int number = letterToNumber(ch);
        if (number == -1){
            throw new NumberFormatException("Invalid format");
        }
        integerValue += number;
    }
    return integerValue;
}
```

Беда заключается в том что когда передаю методу, к примеру, XXIV то получаю 26 вместо 24. Понимаю что весь трабл в `integerValue += number;` в этом месте, но вот как победить, что бы не ломать все что уже написал не могу понять.

З.Ы. Метод letterToNumber:

```
private static int letterToNumber(char letter){
        switch (letter) {
            case 'I':  return 1;
            case 'V':  return 5;
            case 'X':  return 10;
            case 'L':  return 50;
            case 'C':  return 100;
            case 'D':  return 500;
            case 'M':  return 1000;
            default:   return -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: а вы какой средой пользуетесь?

Comment: Кроме того, чтобы смотреть на конкретную цифру, вам придётся ещё и просматривать следующий символ (если он есть) на предмет того, не большего ли значения там цифра. Просто "мапнуть цифры в значения и сложить" работает только для чисел, где цифры идут в строго убывающем по значениям порядке.

Comment: @Viktorov Intellij IDEA. на самом деле решение довольно простым оказалось. всего то после цикла сделал проверку на наличие IV или IX и если true то отнял 2 и все=)

Comment: Ха. Ха. Ха-ха-ха-ха-ха. А на `XL` он даст 40 или 60? :)

Comment: @D-side 60 дает

Comment: А должен бы 40 :)

Comment: Рекомендую посмотреть [статью](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D1%8B) на Википедии. Там есть примеры кода.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class RomanToDecimal {
public static void romanToDecimal(java.lang.String romanNumber) {
    int decimal = 0;
    int lastNumber = 0;
    String romanNumeral = romanNumber.toUpperCase();
    /* operation to be performed on upper cases even if user 
       enters roman values in lower case chars */
    for (int x = romanNumeral.length() - 1; x >= 0 ; x--) {
        char convertToDecimal = romanNumeral.charAt(x);

        switch (convertToDecimal) {
            case 'M':
                decimal = processDecimal(1000, lastNumber, decimal);
                lastNumber = 1000;
                break;

            case 'D':
                decimal = processDecimal(500, lastNumber, decimal);
                lastNumber = 500;
                break;

            case 'C':
                decimal = processDecimal(100, lastNumber, decimal);
                lastNumber = 100;
                break;

            case 'L':
                decimal = processDecimal(50, lastNumber, decimal);
                lastNumber = 50;
                break;

            case 'X':
                decimal = processDecimal(10, lastNumber, decimal);
                lastNumber = 10;
                break;

            case 'V':
                decimal = processDecimal(5, lastNumber, decimal);
                lastNumber = 5;
                break;

            case 'I':
                decimal = processDecimal(1, lastNumber, decimal);
                lastNumber = 1;
                break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(decimal);
}

public static int processDecimal(int decimal, int lastNumber, int lastDecimal) {
    if (lastNumber > decimal) {
        return lastDecimal - decimal;
    } else {
        return lastDecimal + decimal;
    }
}

public static void main(java.lang.String args[]) {
    romanToDecimal("XIV");
}
```

}

Comment: Вот это уже на что-то похоже. Правда, стоит понимать, что внутреннее представление вовсе не обязано быть десятичным (decimal) и более того, скорее всего им и не является. Вместо `decimal` уместнее скорее `value`.

Answer (score 1):

Если нигде не ошибся

```
private static int letterToNumber(char letter){
    switch (letter) {
        case 'I': return 1;
        case 'V': return 5;
        case 'X': return 10;
        case 'L': return 50;
        case 'C': return 100;
        case 'D': return 500;
        case 'M': return 1000;
        default: throw new NumberFormatException("Invalid format");
    }
}

public static int roman2Decimal(String roman){
    if (roman.length() == 0)
      return 0;
    int integerValue = 0;
    int prevNumber = letterToNumber(roman.charAt(0));
    for (int i = 1; i < roman.length(); i++) {
        char ch = roman.charAt(i);
        int number = letterToNumber(ch);
        if (number <= prevNumber)
          integerValue += prevNumber;
        else
          integerValue -= prevNumber;
        prevNumber = number;
    }
    integerValue += prevNumber;
    return integerValue;
}
```

Comment: integerValue -= prevNumber;. мне кажется, мы тут должны добавить к основному числу разницу number - prevNumber; иначе мы из основного числа будет вычитывать только 1 (если вели XXIV, например)

Comment: @SeniorPomidor А на следующей итерации мы прибавим 5

Comment: Посмотрите на ответы https://ideone.com/2hCFH2

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Спасибо. Поправил

Answer (score 1):

вам нужно проверить, что следующее число меньше, чем текущее. Римские числа по убыванию строятся.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(roman2Decimal("I"));
    }
    
    private static int letterToNumber(char letter){
        switch (letter) {
            case 'I':  return 1;
            case 'V':  return 5;
            case 'X':  return 10;
            case 'L':  return 50;
            case 'C':  return 100;
            case 'D':  return 500;
            case 'M':  return 1000;
            default:   return -1;
        }
    }
    
    public static int roman2Decimal(String roman){
    int integerValue = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < roman.length(); i++) {
        char ch = roman.charAt(i);
        int number = letterToNumber(ch);
        if (number == -1) {
            throw new NumberFormatException("Invalid format");
        }

        if (i +1 < roman.length()) {
            int nextNumber = letterToNumber(roman.charAt(i+1));
            if (nextNumber > number) {
                integerValue += (nextNumber - number);
                i++;
            }
            else {
                integerValue += number;
            }
        } else {
            integerValue += number;
            
        }
    }
    return integerValue;
}
```

Comment: поправил условие. спасибо за замечание. не пойму как я его опубликовал так.

Answer (score 1):

Моей первой мыслью было бы найти готовую библиотеку для перевода. И такая библиотека есть: [RomanNumerals](http://frequal.com/RomanNumerals/). С ее помощью можно перевести так:

```
Converter converter = new Converter();
int value = converter.toNumber("MMMCMXCIX");
```

При желании, можно создать конвертер с проверкой переданного римского числа:

```
Converter converter = new Converter(true);
//java.text.ParseException: Cannot subtract V, L, D, or other 5-based numerals in strict mode
int v = converter.toNumber("VX");
//java.text.ParseException: Illegal character: A
int v = converter.toNumber("A");
```

Я проверил библиотеку на числах от 1 до 3999 (полный диапазон) и она работает корректно. Библиотека также умеет преобразывать числа обратно в римскую запись.

Если же это учебная задача и нужно обязательно написать код для конвертации, то и здесь и на английском SO выложено много примеров кода, решающих задачу. Из того что я нашел, самый короткий код [в ответе @Eran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51647368/convert-roman-numeral-to-integer#51647430). Преобразую его в метод:

```
private static final String[] numerals = {"M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L", "XL", "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I"};
private static final int[] values = {1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1};

public static int roman2Decimal(String roman) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numerals.length; i++) {
        while (roman.startsWith(numerals[i])) {
            result += values[i];
            roman = roman.substring(numerals[i].length());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Этот метод не проверяет правильность записи, но корректно работает для правильно записанных римских чисел.

Answer (score 1):

```java
public static int fromRoman(String romanNumeral) {
    return romanNumeral.replace("CM", "DCD").replace("M", "DD")
        .replace("CD", "CCCC").replace("D", "CCCCC")
        .replace("XC","LXL").replace("C", "LL")
        .replace("XL", "XXXX").replace("L", "XXXXX")
        .replace("IX", "VIV").replace("X","VV")
        .replace("IV", "IIII").replace("V", "IIIII").length();
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]